# PHP MYSQL How to automated Add Value to table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create program to automated create class, and every class created then the program automated insert the data to the class.

here my code :

```
$range = range('A', 'Z');
$quota = 100;
$quotaperclass = 25;

for ($x = 0; $x < $quota/$quotaperclass ; $x++) {
        // Automated Create Class
        $sql= "INSERT INTO class(class_id,class_name,prodi_name) values('A25$x','".$range[$x]."','TK')";

        $subquery = "select student_id from alocatedclass"; //Check student already in class 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student.prodi_name='TK' and student.student_id not in ({$subquery}) ORDER by student.student_id ASC LIMIT $quotaperclass";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            // Should insert data to every class
            $sql = "insert into alocatedclass(student_id,class_id) values ('$data[student_id]','A25$x')";
        }
    }
```

Automated Create Class work well, but insert student data to the class is not work. i want like

```
Create Class A
insert student 1
insert student 2
insert student 3
.....
insert student 25    

Create Class B
insert student 26
insert student 27
insert student 28
.....
insert student 50
```

any have solution?

or have better code?

let me know.

or if can add random student, should be better.

and please explain the code, because iam noob in php.

thanks.

Comment: `insert into alocatedclass....` : You aren't ***executing*** that query anywhere

Comment: forget mysql_query. it is a junk. use PDO instead

Comment: @victorino how to use PDO? have any refference?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below line

$sql = "insert into alocatedclass(student_id,class_id) values ('$data[student_id]','A25$x')";

to

$sql = "insert into alocatedclass(student_id,class_id) values (".$data['student_id'].",'A25".$x."')";